# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unrecognized token

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm getting an exception while deleting an entry from the table using the primary key "TransactionID". The TransactionID value is a aphanumeric sequence which contains "-" as well. Below is the LogCat message

---

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unrecognized token : "29e7c8a8" (code 1):, while compiling: DELETE FROM Datas WHERE TransactionID=29e7c8a8-b38b-4812-8a2d
```

---

Is the TranscationID not valid?

Comment: add quotes to TransactionID value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this code**

```
 db.delete(Datas,TransactionID + " = ?",new String[] { "29e7c8a8-b38b-4812-8a2d" });
```

Answer (score 0):

concate it with single quotes

```
DELETE FROM Datas WHERE TransactionID='29e7c8a8-b38b-4812-8a2d'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also get this exception if you try to retrieve or insert a [NULL control character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character) like ["\u0000"](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?utf8=0x) into an SQLite database, using a text query:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE text =
   "Here is a NULL control character \u0000 in the text";
```

Although there is no easy way for a keyboard to type a control character, it's still a valid character in Java String, and it will cause an exception when the String is sent to the Android SQLite database:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unrecognized token (code 1):
  "'Here is a NULL control character ": 
  , while compling: SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE text = '...';
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.native_execSQL(Native Method)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1763)
```

Because it's an invisible character and not easily spotted, you can use a Hex display of the string, to see all the characters. For example, use BBEdit's 'Hex dump front document' as UTF-16LE (Little-Endian).

To avoid this crash, you have to remove this NULL character, using `String.replace()`. See examples here:

- [Java - removing \u0000 from an String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28989970/java-removing-u0000-from-an-string)
- [How to remove control characters from java string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028716/how-to-remove-control-characters-from-java-string)
- [Java string replace and the NUL (NULL, ASCII 0) character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523284/java-string-replace-and-the-nul-null-ascii-0-character)