# Removing whitespaces from string and removing them from char array

Tags: java, string, replaceall

I have an input that recieves a String in java:

```
"a                                                a"
```

(50 characters total, 2 letters and 48 whitespaces)

when i tried

```
replace("\\s++","");
```

or

```
replaceAll("\\s+","");
```

removes the whitespaces, but keeps on the string(char array) with '\u0000' 0
How i remove this to make the string only with 2 characters?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28989970/java-removing-u0000-from-an-string.

Comment: Which char array are you talking about? What is the complete code? And why are you using a regexpt when you could simply use `replace(" ", "")`?

Comment: did you expect `a only one space a` like `a a` or what exactly?

Comment: why do you replace and dont filter the character? where are the whitespaces: at the begining, between the characters, at the end, ...?

Comment: @rperes solution worked. I was tyring to change the string i have to make  smaller, but thanks for all help and tips!

Comment: When you say "2 letters and 48 whitespaces" do you assume that `\u0000` is one of whitespaces? If yes then this is cause of your problem since `\u0000` isn't considered as whitespace so you need to handle it separately. You can check it with `Character.isWhitespace('\u0000')` which returns `false`.

Answer (score 1):

First, I would remind you to keep in mind that the function `replaceAll` returns a new string and does not change the original. Strings in Java are [**immutable**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6952379/4532326).

Then for removing whitespaces and `'\u0000'` just do this:

```
    String a = "a                                                a" ;
    a = a.replaceAll("[\\s\u0000]+","");   // set the result to a;
    System.out.println(a + " " + a.length());
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
aa 2
```

Answer (score -1):

```
   String str = "a                                                a" ;

   str = str.replaceAll(" ", "");
    System.out.println(str);
```